# Randomly select rows from numpy array based on a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have 2 arrays of arrays, **labels** is 1D and **data** is 5D **note that both arrays have the same first dimension**.

To simplify things let's say **labels** contain only 3 arrays :

```
labels=np.array([[0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0],[0,4,0,0,0],[0,3,0,2,1,0,0,1,7,0]])
```

And let's say I have a **datalist** of **data** arrays (length=3) where each array has a 5D shape where the first dimension of each one is the same as the arrays of the **labels** array.

In this example, **datalist** has 3 arrays of shapes : *(**8**,3,100,10,1), (**5**,3,100,10,1) and (**10**,3,100,10,1)* respectively. Here, the first dimension of each of these arrays is the same as the lengths of each array in **label**.

Now I want to reduce the number of zeros in each array of **labels** and keep the other values. Let's say I want to keep only **3 zeros** for each array. Therefore, the length of each array in **labels** as well as the first dimension of each array in **data** will be **6**, **4** and **8**.

In order to reduce the number of zeros in each array of **labels**, I want to randomly select and keep **only 3**. Now these same random selected indexes will be used then to select the correspondant rows from **data**.

For this example, the **new_labels** array will be something like this :

```
new_labels=np.array([[0,0,1,1,2,0],[4,0,0,0],[0,3,2,1,0,1,7,0]])
```

Here's what I have tried so far :

```
all_ind=[] #to store indexes where value=0 for all arrays
indexes_to_keep=[] #to store the random selected indexes
new_labels=[] #to store the final results

for i in range(len(labels)):
    ind=[] #to store indexes where value=0 for one array
    for j in range(len(labels[i])):
        if (labels[i][j]==0):
            ind.append(j)
    all_ind.append(ind)

for k in range(len(labels)):   
    indexes_to_keep.append(np.random.choice(all_ind[i], 3))
    aux= np.zeros(len(labels[i]) - len(all_ind[i]) + 3)
    ....
    .... 
    Here, how can I fill **aux** with the values ?
    ....
    .... 
    new_labels.append(aux)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with numpy arrays of different lenghts is not a good idea therefore you are required to iterate each item and perform some method on it. Assuming you want to optimize that method only, masking might work pretty well here:

```
def specific_choice(x, n):
    '''leaving n random zeros of the list x'''
    x = np.array(x)
    mask = x != 0
    idx = np.flatnonzero(~mask)
    np.random.shuffle(idx) #dynamical change of idx value, quite fast
    idx = idx[:n]
    mask[idx] = True
    return x[mask] # or mask if you need it
```

Iteration of list is faster than one of array so effective usage would be:

```
labels = [[0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0],[0,4,0,0,0],[0,3,0,2,1,0,0,1,7,0]]
output = [specific_choice(n, 3) for n in labels]
```

Output:

```
[array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0]), array([0, 4, 0, 0]), array([0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 1, 7, 0])]
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. `np.random.shuffle` is really a fast option.

Comment: How can I use those exact random indexes to select the corresponding rows from data since the first dimension of each array in data is the same as the arrays in labels ?

Comment: @MejdiDallel Seems like you could modify a definition of method to collect masks instead, something like: `output_of_masks = [specific_choice_masks(n, 3) for n in labels]`  and then do a following comprehension just like so: `[data[mask] for mask in output_of_masks]`.

Comment: Excellent ! I will try that ! And sorry I'm new in Python x)

Comment: @MejdiDallel Alright. More to say, - Pythonic machinery of list or other kind of iterables doesn't allow this kind of indexing. It's a feature of `numpy`libray - it's like an interface that allows to work in Python and perform operations in C level simultaneously.